# How do I get data from stored procedure to xls file?

Tags: c#, sql-server, stored-procedures

```
dgvEmployeeTimeSheet.DataSource  = OCommonFunctions.SelectData("sp_GP_EmployeeTimeSheetDetailSelectForXLS", "@fromdate", dtpFromDate.Value.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy"), "@todate", dtpTODate.Value.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy"), "@companyid", cmbCompany.SelectedValue.ToString());
```

data from the above procedure is to be taken in to

```
for (i = 0; i <= ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count - 1; i++)
       {
           for (j = 0; j <= ds.Tables[0].Columns.Count - 1; j++)
           {
               data = ds.Tables[0].Rows[i].ItemArray[j].ToString();
               xlWorkSheet.Cells[i + 1, j + 1] = data;
           }
       }
```

how do I do it?

Comment: Side note: you should **not** use the `sp_` prefix for your stored procedures. Microsoft has [reserved that prefix for its own use (see *Naming Stored Procedures*)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190669%28v=sql.105%29.aspx), and you do run the risk of a name clash sometime in the future. [It's also bad for your stored procedure performance](http://www.sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/sp_prefix). It's best to just simply avoid `sp_` and use something else as a prefix - or no prefix at all!

Comment: Thank you Marc, If I remove the prefix also how do I get the data to be run in the loop ?

Comment: What is the returning type of OCommonFunctions.SelectData()? How is this function defined?